# Searching for matching elements between 2 arrays in C

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, search

### Question

There are two arrays, one contains a large number of numbers (`arr1`) that may have a few repeating sequences for example 1,2,4 might repeat multiple times in this array. There is another array (`arr2`) that will be assigned by the user.

I need a way to search `arr1` for the exact input the user gave for `arr2`. For a match to be valid, all the elements have to be in the exact same order as entered by the user.

For example, if the user enters 1,2,4,3 the program has to find 1,2,4,3 in that exact order in `arr1`, this means that 1,2,3,4 in arr1 should not be counted as a match. Below is what I have been able to come up with so far, but this returns true even if just the first element of the 2 arrays matches.

```
for (int i=0; i<size1; i++)

{

for (int j = 0; j<size2; j++)

{

if(arr1[i] == arr2[j])

{

printf("found a match %d", j);

break;

}

else if (arr1[i] != arr2[j])

{

printf("not match");

break;

}
```

Below is the complete code :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int arr1[] = {1, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 4, 4, 1, 3, 3};
    int size1 = (int) (sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(arr1));
    
    int arr2[] = {1, 2, 4};
 
 
 
    int size2 = (int) (sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(arr2[0]));

       int match = 0;        
        for (int i=0; i<size1; i++)      
        {
    
            for (int j = 0; j < size2; j++) {
    
                if (arr1[i] != arr2[j]) {
                    match = 1;
                    break;
    
                }
            }
        }
        if(match == 1){
            printf("Not a match");
        }else if(match == 0){
            printf("The lists match");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

if you look at the `arr1` and `arr2`, I need a way to return the index 0,7,13 and also this is still rough since `arr2` is technically dynamic since it is assigned by the user and has no fixed size, only `arr1` will have a fixed size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is similar to finding substrings in a string. But characters are replaced with integers.

Here is a program that will find the matches. It has some debug print statements to show how it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int g_Arr2_Changed=0; //----Global boolean if arr2 changes.
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{ int arr1[] = {1, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 4, 4, 1, 3, 3};
  int size1 = (int) (sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(int));
  int arr2[] = {1, 2, 4};
  int size2 = (int) (sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(int));
  int patternStart  = -1; //----Start pattern in arr1.
  int nPatternMatch =  0; //----Number of ints matched so far.
  for (int i=0; i<size1; i++)
  { int checkInt = arr1[i];
    //printf("[%i](%i)", i, checkInt);
    if (nPatternMatch == 0) //----No integers are matched yet.
    { //printf("<None>");
      //----Is checkInt the start of arr2?
      if (arr2[nPatternMatch] == checkInt)
      { patternStart=i; nPatternMatch++; //printf("<start>");
      }
    }
    else //----At least one integer has been matched already.
    { //printf("<Some>");
      //----Is checkInt a continuation?
      if (arr2[nPatternMatch] == checkInt)
      { nPatternMatch++; //----Matched another integer.
        //printf("<matched>");
      }
      else
      { //printf("<NotMatched>");
        i = patternStart; //---- for() will add one.
        patternStart = - 1;
        nPatternMatch = 0; //----Not match. Start at next int.
      }
    }
    //----If match found print and reset for next.
    if (nPatternMatch == size2)
    { printf("Pattern found at %i\n", patternStart);
      i = patternStart + 1;
      patternStart = -1; nPatternMatch = 0;
    }
    //----Just in case the global variable says arr2 changed.
    if (g_Arr2_Changed != 0) //----Start over.
    { //printf("<arr2 changed.>");
      i=0; patternStart = -1; nPatternMatch = 0;
      size2 = (int) (sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(int));
    }
    //printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will return a match for every character that is found in the same position in both lists.
So if you you want to verify the whole list, you should set an int, to identify if there is even one character that doesn't match in both lists. 
If you want to show the list that match, you just have to print the whole list inside the second if.

```
        int match = 0;        
        for (int i=0; i<size1; i++)      
        {
    
            for (int j = 0; j < size2; j++) {
    
                if (arr1[i] != arr2[j]) {
                    match = 1;
                    break;
    
                }
            }
            if(match == 1){
                printf("Not a match");
            }else if(match == 0){
                printf("The lists match");
                printf("First character: %c", arr2[0]);
            }
            match = 0; 
        }
```

Comment: You can ask me any

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, but I still have a few problems, basically my issue is that arr1 will be a fixed array, but arr2 will be dynamic since the user will assign in so I need a way to compare what ever elements the user gives to arr1 and only return something if the whole user string is matched to arr1. I have provided more code in my original question if you can pls look at that. in arr1 the string of arr2 is repeated multiple times, so I need my program to find all those times it is repeated and return the index of the first number in the string. output: 0, 7, 13 should be the output.

Comment: I altered the code, to show separately if any of strings os the arr2 match, and show the first character of this string.

Comment: I tried the code again and for some reason, it prints Not a Match, but arr2 is assigned as int arr2[] = {1, 2, 4}; which occurs 3 times in arr1. Also, I don't understand how you program will verify that 1,2,4 are all present in arr1 in a sequence because if it was 1,4,4 that should not be considered as a matching list. Lastly, I don't need a way to return the first character of the array, rather I need a way to return the index of where all the matches were found so if we use arr2 is 1,2,4 it should tell us that the indices where this is found is 0,7,13

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr1[] = {1, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 4, 4, 1, 3, 3};
    int size1 = sizeof arr1 / sizeof arr1[0];

    int arr2[] = {1, 2, 4};
    int size2 = sizeof arr2 / sizeof arr2[0];

    int match;
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < size1 - size2 + 1; i++) {
        match = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < size2; j++) {
            if (arr1[i + j] != arr2[j]) {
                match = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (! match) {
            printf("matched at %d\n", i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It will output:

```
matched at 0
matched at 7
matched at 13
```

If you want to assign an array to the list of the matched indices, it will be easy for you to modify the code.